# beautiful Highlight selected button in Navigation bar

Tags: html, css

i want to add "beautiful highlight" to selected button. Please see image

[image]

Highlight in My current link is not "clear": https://jsfiddle.net/bvotcode/axc2ogby/13/

(from Original: https://codepen.io/lakshmiR/pen/wzPmyd)

[image]

Does anybody know how to use css to do it?

I really appereciate if somebody can help me.

Thank in advance

CSS

```
body {
        background: none #000;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .logo {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: burlywood;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 3vw;
        font-family: cursive;
        height: 90vh;
    }
    .sticky .logo{
        height: 0;
    }
    ul.menu {
        text-align: center;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 2vh 0;
    }
    .sticky ul.menu {
        padding: 1vh 0;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: none #000;
    }
    ul.menu li {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0 2vw 0 0;
    }
    ul.menu li.last {
        margin: 0;
    }
    ul.menu li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 2vw;
        font-family: cursive;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    ul.menu li a.active, ul.menu li a:hover {
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
    ul.menu li.news a {
        color: #36d341;
    }
    ul.menu li.tour a {
        color: #ff25e8;
    }
    ul.menu li.video a {
        color: #7353ff;
    }
    ul.menu li.music a {
        color: #3dc6ff;
    }
    ul.menu li.photo a {
        color: #ecee24;
    }
    ul.menu li.album a {
        color: #fa6d27;
    }
    #content > div {
        padding: 45vh 0;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 2vw;
        font-family: monospace;
    }
    #content #news {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(-34deg,#3434f7 0%,#34c8ff 50%,#27ef77 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-34deg,#3434f7 0%,#34c8ff 50%,#27ef77 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(-34deg,#3434f7 0%,#34c8ff 50%,#27ef77 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(-34deg,#3434f7 0%,#34c8ff 50%,#27ef77 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(124deg,#3434f7 0%,#34c8ff 50%,#27ef77 100%);
    }
    #content #tour {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(-34deg,#ecee24 0%,#EC4e24 50%,#fa6d27 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-34deg,#ecee24 0%,#EC4e24 50%,#fa6d27 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(-34deg,#ecee24 0%,#EC4e24 50%,#fa6d27 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(-34deg,#ecee24 0%,#EC4e24 50%,#fa6d27 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(124deg,#ecee24 0%,#EC4e24 50%,#fa6d27 100%);
    }
    #content #video {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(-34deg,#f21c36 0%,#ff26cf 50%,#a626ff 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-34deg,#f21c36 0%,#ff26cf 50%,#a626ff 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(-34deg,#f21c36 0%,#ff26cf 50%,#a626ff 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(-34deg,#f21c36 0%,#ff26cf 50%,#a626ff 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(124deg,#f21c36 0%,#ff26cf 50%,#a626ff 100%);
    }
    #content #music {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(-34deg,#36D341 0%,#4AC326 50%,#3DC6FF 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-34deg,#36D341 0%,#4AC326 50%,#3DC6FF 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(-34deg,#36D341 0%,#4AC326 50%,#3DC6FF 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(-34deg,#36D341 0%,#4AC326 50%,#3DC6FF 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(124deg,#36D341 0%,#4AC326 50%,#3DC6FF 100%);
    }
    #content #photo {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(-34deg,#f42df6 0%,#be34ff 50%,#4827ef 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-34deg,#f42df6 0%,#be34ff 50%,#4827ef 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(-34deg,#f42df6 0%,#be34ff 50%,#4827ef 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(-34deg,#f42df6 0%,#be34ff 50%,#4827ef 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(124deg,#f42df6 0%,#be34ff 50%,#4827ef 100%);
    }
    #content #album {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(-34deg,#F21D36 0%,#AAEEDD 50%,#FE1245 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-34deg,#F21D36 0%,#AAEEDD 50%,#FE1245 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(-34deg,#F21D36 0%,#AAEEDD 50%,#FE1245 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(-34deg,#F21D36 0%,#AAEEDD 50%,#FE1245 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(124deg,#F21D36 0%,#AAEEDD 50%,#FE1245 100%);
    }
    #footer {
        padding: 2vw 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="logo">
        Sticky Nav and Nav Highlight on page scroll
    </div>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="first leaf news">
            <a href="#news" title="" class="">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf tour">
            <a href="#tour" title="" class="">Tour</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf video">
            <a href="#video" title="" class="">Video</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf music">
            <a href="#music" title="" class="">Music</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf photo">
            <a href="#photo" title="" class="">Photo</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf album last">
            <a href="#album" title="" class="">Album</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="news">
        News
    </div>
    <div id="tour">
        Tour
    </div>
    <div id="video">
        Video
    </div>
    <div id="music">
        Music
    </div>
    <div id="photo">
        Photo
    </div>
    <div id="album">
        Album
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div class="footer-tos">
        <a href="" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example the section which takes more viewport height is active.

Demo:
https://codepen.io/ArtZ91/pen/oNGoqPV

[image: Percent-based active section search]

Example with your html & css code below:

```js
jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  var navHeight = jQuery('ul.menu').height();
  if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
    jQuery('body').addClass('sticky');
  } else {
    jQuery('body').removeClass('sticky');
  }
});


// Scroll watcher

function getViewportHeight() {
  return window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}

function scrollWatch() {
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".scroll-watcher-item");
  if (!elements) {
    return;
  }
  [].forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
    scrollWatchElement(element);
  });
  scrollWatch__UpdateActiveMenuItem();
}

function scrollWatch__UpdateActiveMenuItem() {
  let menu_items = document.querySelectorAll("#navigation a");
  if (!menu_items) {
    return;
  }
  [].forEach.call(menu_items, function(item) {
    item.classList.remove("active");
  });
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".scroll-watcher-item");
  if (!elements) {
    return;
  }
  let active_expectant = null;
  let active_expectant_percent = 0;
  [].forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
    let percent = parseFloat(element.getAttribute("data-watcher-percent"));
    if (percent > active_expectant_percent) {
      active_expectant = element;
      active_expectant_percent = percent;
    }
  });
  if (!active_expectant) {
    return;
  }
  let active_menu_item_id = active_expectant.getAttribute("id");
  let active_menu_item = document.querySelector('#navigation a[href="#' + active_menu_item_id + '"]');
  if (!active_menu_item) {
    return;
  }
  active_menu_item.classList.add("active");
}

function scrollWatchElement(element) {
  let viewportHeight = getViewportHeight();
  if (!element) {
    return;
  }
  let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  let top = rect.top;
  if (top < 0) top = 0;
  if (top > viewportHeight) top = viewportHeight;
  let bottom = rect.bottom;
  if (bottom < 0) bottom = 0;
  if (bottom > viewportHeight) bottom = viewportHeight;
  let percent = Math.round((100 * (bottom - top)) / viewportHeight, 2);
  element.setAttribute("data-watcher-percent", percent);
}

// https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event
let ticking = false;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        scrollWatch();
        ticking = false;
      }, 250);
    });
    ticking = true;
  }
});

scrollWatch();
```

```css
body {
  background: none #000;
  margin: 0;
}

.logo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: burlywood;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-family: cursive;
  height: 90vh;
}

.sticky .logo {
  height: 0;
}

ul.menu {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2vh 0;
}

.sticky ul.menu {
  padding: 1vh 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: none #000;
}

ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 1vw;
}

ul.menu li.last {
  margin: 0;
}

ul.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-family: cursive;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0 1vw;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

ul.menu li.news a {
  color: #36d341;
}

ul.menu li.tour a {
  color: #ff25e8;
}

ul.menu li.video a {
  color: #7353ff;
}

ul.menu li.music a {
  color: #3dc6ff;
}

ul.menu li.photo a {
  color: #ecee24;
}

ul.menu li.album a {
  color: #fa6d27;
}

ul.menu li a.active {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}

#content>div {
  padding: 45vh 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#content #news {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-34deg, #3434f7 0%, #34c8ff 50%, #27ef77 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-34deg, #3434f7 0%, #34c8ff 50%, #27ef77 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-34deg, #3434f7 0%, #34c8ff 50%, #27ef77 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-34deg, #3434f7 0%, #34c8ff 50%, #27ef77 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(124deg, #3434f7 0%, #34c8ff 50%, #27ef77 100%);
}

#content #tour {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-34deg, #ecee24 0%, #EC4e24 50%, #fa6d27 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-34deg, #ecee24 0%, #EC4e24 50%, #fa6d27 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-34deg, #ecee24 0%, #EC4e24 50%, #fa6d27 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-34deg, #ecee24 0%, #EC4e24 50%, #fa6d27 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(124deg, #ecee24 0%, #EC4e24 50%, #fa6d27 100%);
}

#content #video {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-34deg, #f21c36 0%, #ff26cf 50%, #a626ff 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-34deg, #f21c36 0%, #ff26cf 50%, #a626ff 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-34deg, #f21c36 0%, #ff26cf 50%, #a626ff 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-34deg, #f21c36 0%, #ff26cf 50%, #a626ff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(124deg, #f21c36 0%, #ff26cf 50%, #a626ff 100%);
}

#content #music {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-34deg, #36D341 0%, #4AC326 50%, #3DC6FF 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-34deg, #36D341 0%, #4AC326 50%, #3DC6FF 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-34deg, #36D341 0%, #4AC326 50%, #3DC6FF 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-34deg, #36D341 0%, #4AC326 50%, #3DC6FF 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(124deg, #36D341 0%, #4AC326 50%, #3DC6FF 100%);
}

#content #photo {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-34deg, #f42df6 0%, #be34ff 50%, #4827ef 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-34deg, #f42df6 0%, #be34ff 50%, #4827ef 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-34deg, #f42df6 0%, #be34ff 50%, #4827ef 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-34deg, #f42df6 0%, #be34ff 50%, #4827ef 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(124deg, #f42df6 0%, #be34ff 50%, #4827ef 100%);
}

#content #album {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-34deg, #F21D36 0%, #AAEEDD 50%, #FE1245 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-34deg, #F21D36 0%, #AAEEDD 50%, #FE1245 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-34deg, #F21D36 0%, #AAEEDD 50%, #FE1245 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-34deg, #F21D36 0%, #AAEEDD 50%, #FE1245 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(124deg, #F21D36 0%, #AAEEDD 50%, #FE1245 100%);
}

#footer {
  padding: 2vw 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div class="logo">
    Sticky Nav and Nav Highlight on page scroll
  </div>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="first leaf news">
      <a href="#news" title="" class="scroll-to-anchor" data-scroll-offset="0">News</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf tour">
      <a href="#tour" title="" class="scroll-to-anchor" data-scroll-offset="0">Tour</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf video">
      <a href="#video" title="" class="scroll-to-anchor" data-scroll-offset="0">Video</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf music">
      <a href="#music" title="" class="scroll-to-anchor" data-scroll-offset="0">Music</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf photo">
      <a href="#photo" title="" class="scroll-to-anchor" data-scroll-offset="0">Photo</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf album last">
      <a href="#album" title="" class="scroll-to-anchor" data-scroll-offset="0">Album</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="news" class="scroll-watcher-item">
    News
  </div>
  <div id="tour" class="scroll-watcher-item">
    Tour
  </div>
  <div id="video" class="scroll-watcher-item">
    Video
  </div>
  <div id="music" class="scroll-watcher-item">
    Music
  </div>
  <div id="photo" class="scroll-watcher-item">
    Photo
  </div>
  <div id="album" class="scroll-watcher-item">
    Album
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="footer-tos">
    <a href="" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a>
  </div>
</div>
```